# How to solve "fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections" while using Java native interface?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, native, solaris

I'm trying to call a C function inside a Java code.
I have this hava code.

```
public class JavaToC {

    public native void helloC();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaToC().helloC();
    }
}
```

. I compiled it and then created header file. Then make the following HelloWorld.c file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "JavaToC.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JavaToC_helloC(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaobj)
{
  printf("Hello World: From C");
  return;
}
```

I tried compiling this using "gcc -o libHelloWorld.so -shared -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/solaris HelloWorld.c -lc", but it gives the following result.

```
Text relocation remains                     referenced
    against symbol          offset  in file
.rodata (section)                   0x9         /var/tmp//cc.GaGrd.o
printf                              0xe         /var/tmp//cc.GaGrd.o
ld: fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm working on Solaris 11, how can I solve this?

Comment: I have added a Solaris tag because I feel this might be relevant. Feel free to remove it if you disagree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot test this on a Solaris machine at the moment, but from http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/SPARC-Options.html

> `-mimpure-text` suppresses the “relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections” linker error message. However, the
>   necessary relocations will trigger copy-on-write, and the shared
>   object is not actually shared across processes. Instead of using
>   `-mimpure-text`, you should compile all source code with `-fpic` or `-fPIC`.

the solution seems to be to add the `-fpic` option to generate position-independent code.

Comment: Thanks you very, very much!! After a few days trying to compile mod_perl for Apache in Solaris 10 with your help I have succeeded at last :-)