# Getting Error When Building Apache2 on Solaris Server

Tags: apache, mod-lua

I am building Apache2 (ver - 2.4.41) on Solaris server.

```
/usr/sfw/bin/gmake
```

Getting below error :

```
ld: fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[4]: *** [mod_lua.la] Error 1
gmake[4]: Leaving directory `/prodlib/ESTVN/httpd-2.4.41/modules/lua'
gmake[3]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/prodlib/ESTVN/httpd-2.4.41/modules/lua'
gmake[2]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/prodlib/ESTVN/httpd-2.4.41/modules'
gmake[1]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/prodlib/ESTVN/httpd-2.4.41'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18813132/2908599) you need to add this in to the make command:

```
-fpic
```

(generate position-independent code)